# BERT pre-training from scratch with tensorflow version 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model, tpu

i used `run_pretraining.py` (https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_pretraining.py) python script in `tensorflow version 1.15.5` version before. I use Google cloud TPU, as well.
Is it possible or any python script for BERT pre-training from scratch on TPU using tensorflow version 2.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use [NPL library](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/nlp) from [TF2 model garden](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official).

The instructions for creating training data and running pretraining are here:
[nlp/docs/train.md#pre-train-a-bert-from-scratch](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/nlp/docs/train.md#pre-train-a-bert-from-scratch).

You can also follow [BERT Fine Tuning with Cloud TPU](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/bert-2.x) tutorial with some changes to run pretraining script instead of fine tuning.